# Why using global variabes makes the multi-threaded execution 2x slower while in other environment it makes it 2x faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, g++, visual-studio-2019

The code below was taken from an example compiled with g++. The multi-threaded was 2x faster than the single-threaded.

I'm executing it in Visual Studio 2019 and the results are the opposite: the single-threaded is 2x faster than the multi-threaded.

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;

using ll = long long;
ll odd, even;
void par(const ll ini, const ll fim)
{
    for (auto i = ini; i <= fim; i++)
        if (!(i & 1))
            even += i;
        
}

void impar(const ll ini, const ll fim)
{
    for (auto i = ini; i <= fim; i++)
        if (i & 1)
            odd += i;
}
int main()
{
    const ll start = 0;
    const ll end = 190000000;

/* SINGLE THREADED */
    auto start_single = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    par(start, end);
    impar(start, end);
    auto end_single = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto single_duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end_single - start_single).count();
    cout << "SINGLE THREADED\nEven sum: " << even << "\nOdd sum: " << odd << "\nTime: " << single_duration << "ms\n\n\n";
/* END OF SINGLE*/

/* MULTI THREADED */
    even = odd = 0;
    auto start_multi= chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    thread t(par, start, end);
    thread t2(impar, start, end);
    t.join();
    t2.join();
    auto end_multi = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto multi_duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end_multi - start_multi).count();
    cout << "MULTI THREADED\nEven sum: " << even << "\nOdd sum: " << odd << "\nTime: " << multi_duration << "ms\n";
/*END OF MULTI*/
    cout << "\n\nIs multi faster than single? => " << boolalpha << (multi_duration < single_duration) << '\n';
}
```

However, If I do a small modification on my functions as shown below:

```
void par(const ll ini, const ll fim)
{
    ll temp = 0;
    for (auto i = ini; i <= fim; i++)
        if (!(i & 1))
            temp += i;
    even = temp;
}

void impar(const ll ini, const ll fim)
{
    ll temp = 0;
    for (auto i = ini; i <= fim; i++)
        if (i & 1)
            temp += i;
    odd = temp;
}
```

The multi-threaded performs better. I would like to know what leads to this behavior (what are the possible differences in implementation that explains it).

Also, I have compiled with gcc from [www.onlinegdb.com](http://www.onlinegdb.com) and the results are similar to Visual Studio's in my machine.

Comment: You should specify optimization settings when you built the program.  If you're timing a "debug" or unoptimized builds, the timings are meaningless.

Comment: The globals - `ll odd, even;` are probably stored near each other and probably on the same cache line.  The 2 threads which update the globals inside the loop will be fighting for control of the single cache line.  The versions which use stack locals will have no need to access the cache line until the end of the loop - no contention.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie both debug and release mode have the behaviors that I mentioned

Comment: @rafix07 that doesn't change the execution time in my environment... I'm wondering why the guy from the video executed it with G++ and it got better performance and when I tried that compiler in the website it didnt. And also, what could be the difference between the compilers implementation that leads to this behavior

Comment: @RichardCritten you mean that they are locking the resource somehow? If they were in different cache lines then it should work?

Comment: @RichardCritten you are right! I've tried putting some space between them in memory: `ll odd, random_stuf[100000], even; ` and the perfomance improved
`

Comment: This may not matter for your speed testing but be aware that using global variables without making them atomic or using mutex locks means that none of the results can be trusted. Two CPU cores could execute `even += 1` at the same time and only add 1 to the result. Or more extreme, one core could issue a memory write for `even + 1`, get interrupted, other cores add thousands more to it, then the first core comes back, finishes the write and resets the value back, losing thousands of updates.

Comment: Your rewritten `impar()` function is trivial, equivalent to `odd = 0;`  Fix that error and your results may change...

Comment: @BenVoigt just fixed that. I wasn't really checking the function results, just the time it took to execute and guess I hitted more `Ctrl + z` than I expected when asking the question

Comment: @vmp: We've all been guility of that.  However the optimizing compiler pays close attention and will happily remove an entire loop that has no effect on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a victim of [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads.html).

`odd` and `even` reside next to each other, and accessing them from two threads leads to L3 cache line contention (a.k.a *false sharing*).

You can fix it by spreading them by 64 bytes to make sure they reside in different cache lines, for example, like this:

```
alignas(64) ll odd, even;
```

With that change I get good speedup with 2 threads:

```
SINGLE THREADED
Even sum: 9025000095000000
Odd sum: 9025000000000000
Time: 825954ms


MULTI THREADED
Even sum: 9025000095000000
Odd sum: 9025000000000000
Time: 532420ms
```

As for G++ performance - it might be performing the optimization you made manually for you. MSVC is more careful when it comes to optimizing global variables.

Comment: Makes sense... So the difference in the results is not due to compiler implementation details but to processor architecture? If not, do you have any guesses why in the video he didn't get false sharing?

Comment: Yes, most probably g++ just optimized the code better.

Comment: @vmp Watch the first few mins of this presentation - it goes through an overview of current hardware with respect to multi-threading - CppCon 2017: Fedor Pikus “C++ atomics, from basic to advanced. What do they really do?” - https://youtu.be/ZQFzMfHIxng

Comment: @vmp multithreading gets really complicated really fast. There is so much of what I'll call "Weird Smurf" that no one can cover it all in a video or even a whole course. Most of the time you see the stuff that you WILL get slapped around by being covered and the stuff you MAY see getting only a note in a sidebar, if you're lucky.

Comment: @rustyx I was running both without optimizations. When I activated optimizations it worked without needing `alignas` and got a little bit faster than when used alignas.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know, indeed it seems that MSVC's optimizer is not that bad after all and is able to hoist global variable access out of the loop ([godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6YG5q9oj8)).

Comment: @vmp: Performance measurements are meaningless with optimizations turned off.